# В заключение или в заключении?

Tags: пунктуация

Если предложение начинается со слов "Отметим в заключении, что..." и это последний абзац статьи, т.е. Заключение, то нужно писать -е или -и?

Answer (score 1):

В заключен**ие**, то есть в конце, обычно подводят итог, а вот в заключен**ии** можно находиться, либо пребывать. Хотя прародителем обоих слов является «ключ», и по сути они схожи: в первом замыкают и во втором замыкают, - это два различных слова, ибо в первом – замыкают мысль, а во втором – человека.

Comment: Только прЕбывать. Спасибо.

Comment: Вы правы: прибыть можно в место заключения, а в заключении - только пребывать:)

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: отметим в заключение.

ПАРНЫЙ ВАРИАНТ

Отметим в заключение (чтобы закрыть/закончить текст, подвести итог), направленный В.п. со значением цели - в заключении книги (где) коротко рассказывается о дальнейшей судьбе героев, ненаправленный П.п.

Comment: Но вот, чего я интуитивно и инстинктивно всегда не понимала: статья ведь тоже имеет заключение, и если там в конце говорится "и в заключение (-и) отметим" или "отметим в заключение (-и)", то ведь можно и поставить вопрос "где?", т.е. это будет обстоятельство места? Или я не права и в научных и литературных трудах принято говорить "в заключение"? Чтобы уже раз навсегда развязаться с этим вопросом...

Comment: Если в значении "под конец" - это фразеологизм - обстоятельство, но не места, а образа действия - как? - в заключение. Заключение как вывод есть у экспертизы. У романа тоже есть заключение, конец, но Вы же не в нём будете что-то отмечать, а в своей речи, под конец своей речи.

Comment: Отметить в заключение (чтобы закончить текст) - обстоятельство цели. Рассказать в заключительной части (в заключении) - обстоятельство места.